# Is it possible to change the default duration for a new event in Calendar from 60 min to 30 min

Tags: macos, calendar

I know I can adjust it while I'm creating the event, and I can always change it afterwards, but I'd like the default to be 30 min, as that works best for me.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what platform (Mac, iPhone, iPad, etc.) and what version of the operating system is on these devices that you need to change this on. Without that information we may not be able to answer your question.

Comment: Also include what application you're talking about.  Making this change will be different if you're asking about the default Calendar vs a 3rd-party app.

Answer (score 16):

You can change the Mac's Calendar default duration for a new event using a terminal command.

Go to `Applications`>`Utilities`>`Terminal` and enter the following command in terminal:

`defaults write com.apple.iCal 'Default duration in minutes for new event' 30`

The default duration should then be 30 minutes. You can change it to another value by changing the number `30` to whatever you wish.

If you wish to revert back the default 60 minutes, you can enter the following command in terminal:

`defaults delete com.apple.iCal 'Default duration in minutes for new event'`

This works on macOS Mojave 10.14.6 and suspect it does for macOS Catalina too.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a command line setting to change the default events to be created as all day?   I swear there used to be a setting to change that, but I can't find anything and all new events on my mac are being created at 9am for an hour the day of the event and I'd rather have them set to all day and manually change that if I need to.

Comment: @Morwen Can't you just create an event by double clicking in the "All Day Events" bar above the hourly-breakdown of your calendar? This bar should be visible in day and weekly view. If not, check the view options by going to the menu bar and select `View`>`Show all-day events`

Comment: @Morwen I've written an answer on creating all day events in iCal, perhaps it's helpful: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/441078/24324

Answer (score 0):

You don't need terminal to change the default event time.

Open Calendar -> Settings -> Default event duration -> Change from 1 hour to 30 minutes

Comment: when I answered the question in 2020, there was no settings option to set the default event duration in iCal/Calendar in macOS Big Sur or earlier, so things may have changed since macOS Monterey or later, but I can't confirm since I do not have macOS Monterey/Ventura/Sonoma on my MacBook Pro