# How to change default event time in Calendar (iCal) using Big Sur

Tags: macos, mac, big-sur, ical

I would like to change the default event time in ical from one hour to 15 min. Using BigSur 11.2.3. I have tried to enter the following in terminal, and it does not work. Any help appreciated!

```
defaults write com.apple.iCal 'Default duration in minutes for new event' 15
```

Comment: Are you quitting/relaunching afterwards?

Comment: Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/382657/is-it-possible-to-change-the-default-duration-for-a-new-event-in-calendar-from-6