# How to change the event default duration of the iPhone calendar?

Tags: iphone, calendar

Anyone knows how to change the event default duration of the iPhone calendar ?

I would like the events to be 30min long by default but it seems to be stuck at 1h which is very annoying.

It is possible to do it with this solution on MacOS : [https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/382657/is-it-possible-to-change-the-default-duration-for-a-new-event-in-calendar-from-6#:~:text=You%20can%20change%20the%20Mac's,event%20using%20a%20terminal%20command.&text=The%20default%20duration%20should%20then,30%20to%20whatever%20you%20wish.&text=This%20works%20on%20macOS%20Mojave%2010.14](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/382657/is-it-possible-to-change-the-default-duration-for-a-new-event-in-calendar-from-6#:%7E:text=You%20can%20change%20the%20Mac%27s,event%20using%20a%20terminal%20command.&text=The%20default%20duration%20should%20then,30%20to%20whatever%20you%20wish.&text=This%20works%20on%20macOS%20Mojave%2010.14). but I don't know how to do it on iOS...

Anyone knows the solution ? It's really strange that something that simple is not possible...

Thx !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPhone Calendar
Set Default Event Duration

1. Exit Calendar App
2. Open normal iPhone Settings app
3. Scroll down to “Calendar” and tap it
4. Scroll to “Duration for New Events”, tap it
5. Choose from lots of possibilities…
6. You’re done, exit Settings, go back to Calendar and try a few to see if you like the results! If not, repeat and rinse!

I discovered this by simply browsing Settings looking for something else.
WEIRD LOCATION for such a simple fix!

Comment: Note within iOS you can't set your own random number by default, like you can on macOS, but you have multiple options including 15, 25, 30, 45, 50, 55, 60, 90, 120 minutes. Alternative you can manually edit the event for other times...

Comment: So cool Apple finally implemented this feature !

Answer (score 1):

In iOS and iPadOS, it is currently not possible to change the default event duration.